# Javascript: CORS enabled image

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, cors, todataurl

I want to be able to convert Canvas (which contains image from another domain) to Image. For this as I understood I should use CORS enabled images (to be able to use .toDataURL() for canvas). The question is how to make CORS enabled image. The following code throws an error on first line: *Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.*

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" id="button" value="convert" onclick="onClick()" /></br>
<img id="output" />

<script>
    var source = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7b67c827ee1671ba3b43f4aebf6794fb?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG";

    onClick = function () {
        var img = document.createElement('img');

        img.onload = function (e) {
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            var url = canvas.toDataURL();
            var output = document.getElementById("output");
            output.src = url;
        };

        img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
        img.src = source;
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uhm, you'd have to actually add the header on the server that the image is on, not in the javascript code that gets it ?

Comment: and what if the image is on my local drive and this code is running from the same machine?

Comment: @Qvatra Is your machine running a web server? If so, [configure your web server to serve CORS headers](http://enable-cors.org/server.html). If you are accessing the image via `file://`, access is disabled for security reasons: imagine if any HTML document you opened could read images from your local drive without your consent.

Comment: @apsillers no, no web server at my machine running. I'm just want to get image from my hard disc, draw it on canvas and convert it to another Image.

Answer (score 3):

Hi Suggest you check compability if you need IE I'm not sure this approach will work for you.

See here, with help on CORS enabling your images. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_Enabled_Image

Essentially the CORS header is added to the webserver from which the image is being served, so this has to be under your control to some degree.

As I've always needed IE the simplest solution I have found is to simply setup a server side proxy to serve the images as if they come from your domain.

HTH

Comment: I saw the link.. But I don't know where to include the header if the image is on my local drive and this code is running from the same machine?

Comment: You need to set up a server on your local machine and then set the headers to cors-enable a site created on your local machine: http://enable-cors.org/  Alternatively during development, you could temporarily host your images on a cors-enabled site like http://dropbox.com.

Comment: @markE [here is opinion that dropbox is not cors enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757891/cross-origin-image-load-from-cross-enabled-site-is-denied/20757960?noredirect=1#20757960)

Comment: Dropbox.com's public folder is CORS enabled: jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/u8nxd