# How to get color that is behind a transparent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a site where the body has many color. When the content is scrolled down the background of the content changes. 
In the below image u can see body text with blue color background. So when the content is scrolled down with the scrollbar then the background image should also scroll along with the content. 
So what happens is when scroll bar stops at a color like blue then automatically the menu header(Home) background should change to blue.

Comment: Please show your code, a beautiful picture is not enough

Comment: Are you using a gradient for the background???

Comment: @Wisam: i've taken very large image of height 1551 px. i need to loop this picture when scrolled.

Comment: Do you have another block in between home and content?? the grey band??

Comment: Are you seriously going to use this background? Sorry but I would avoid your website as it hurts my eyes.

Comment: @putvande: it is client's requirement. but the original page looks good. All colors are not seen at once.

Comment: Hmm basically you want to have the background data of where that current element is? Well you want to get pixel properties aka the color of a pixel. However you cannot get this with a plain image, but you can with a canvas image. I made a prototype http://jsfiddle.net/7rkgx/ but you should find a way to convert a image to canvas and it will fully work. *Note that you can't change the width and height in CSS, it should be adjusted in the canvas properties. This is the direction to go i think.

Comment: @nkmol it's not working.

Comment: @madhukumar Did your header wasn't positioned right or did it really not work? http://jsfiddle.net/7rkgx/1/

Comment: @nkmol: hi nkmol it's working but there is small problem. the color changes only when the scroll bar stops scrolling. it should change it's color when the scroll content is scrolling. not after scroll bar stops.

Comment: @madhukumar Ah yea, i intentionally added that ^^ Here is the live scroll event: http://jsfiddle.net/7rkgx/2/ Though, I still not completely feel this being worthy as an answer, as the canvas is hard coded and is not easy to create your own background(as it also would result in some memory spikes, certainly when using a big background). Though i will examine some more.

Comment: @nkmol: u r Superman. thank u. ok, pls tell me after u examine without using canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all we should know what we want to do. Step one is actually get a color of the image, thus acces a property of the image. 
However the browser cannot get direct information of the image itself(You can, of course, get information from the element of the image). However one webbrowser drawing method let us control every aspect of a image: Canvas.

So first we have to convert our image to an canvas element.
This is fairly simply done with `drawImage(img, posx, posy, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);`

We will also stretch the canvas image + the element to the entire screen. The reason we want to define to size also at the canvas is because this way the canvas will calculate every new generated pixel, so we can acces every of the new pixels:

```
var screenWidth = window.innerWidth,
    screenHeight = window.innerHeight,
    c = document.createElement('canvas');
    ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    img = document.getElementById("image");

    c.width = screenWidth;
    c.height = screenHeight;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    $(c).attr('id', 'c');
    $('body').prepend(c);
    $(img).remove();
```

An Canvas element as is dynamically made and will fit to the screen size(Note that this is only at first start of the webbrowser. So when you resize the canvas will not resize with the screen).

We remove the image as it is no use anymore. It's a good practive to transform from image to canvas in my opinion. As you will be certain that the image will be loaded in the browser first and then transformed to a canvas element.

Next we're going to acces a pixel. You can acces pixel data with `getImageData(offsetX, offsetY, sizeX, sizeY).data;` And RGBA color array will be returned.

Now the offsetX and offsetY will be the offset of the element color picker. **Note that this elements offset should be relative to the webbrowsers viewport as the background is fixed** You can do this with `getBoundingClientRect();`
The size is just 1x1 as we want 1 pixel.

This all should happen when the user is scrolling, you can catch the scroll event with `.scroll(function);` :

```
   $(window).scroll(function () {
        var offset = document.getElementById('color').getBoundingClientRect(),
            offsetX = offset.left,
            offsetY = offset.top;

        var color = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d').getImageData(offsetX, offsetY, 1, 1).data;
        $('header').css('background-color',"rgba("+ color[0] + ', ' + color[1] + ', '+ color[2] + ', ' + color[3] + ")");
    });
```

Where we add the rgba array colors just with the first 4 indexes(Because and rgba collor pattern never has more as 4 values) with plain css to the `header` element.

### Loading External image into a canvas

When you want to transform an external image to a canvas element you might get this error:

**Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.**

It is for [security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) reasons that you can't fully acces this image.

As explained here: [HTML 5 canvas getImageData from an externally-loaded image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869844/html-5-canvas-getimagedata-from-an-externally-loaded-image)

There are some external hosts that supports this, for example [dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com).

**Local**

However when you just store it locally it will just work fine.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2Lyz/)

*This method was tested in chrome, IE and firefox.*

**I want to use those external (dropbox) files**

I'm not sure why this happens but for some reason with this method there are still some security diffecults. To enable this [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) you have to add a image property `.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";`. However when you load the image with HTML the the element has been made without this property. So you should assign this property when the image is created:

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("c"),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        screenWidth = window.innerWidth,
        screenHeight = window.innerHeight;
    // Using image WITH crossOrigin=anonymous
    // Succeeds in Chrome+Mozilla, Still fails in IE
    var externalImage2 = new Image();
    externalImage2.onload = function(){
        canvas.width= screenWidth;
        canvas.height= screenHeight;
        ctx.drawImage(externalImage2, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        // this will FAIL on a CORS violation
    }
    externalImage2.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";                     
    externalImage2.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8g8lgmdx341j1d6/rainbow_gradient_horizontal.jpg";
```

This is just an picture i uploaded to my dropbox where i just shared the photo. Note:

> The way to convert a share link to a direct link is to change the domain from "www.dropbox.com" to "dl.dropboxusercontent.com". See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/53/programmatically-download-content-from-share-links.

source: [Cross-origin image load from cross-enabled site is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757891/cross-origin-image-load-from-cross-enabled-site-is-denied)

This creates an image and puts it into an *excisting* canvas element. So note that you should have a canvas element into your HTML.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6BHQ/2/)

This method does only work for chrome and firefox as other browsers still have some security issues.

*Additional note is the pixel that gets captured is the top-left pixel of the 'color-pick' element*. You can adjust this offset if you want it to catch, for example, the middle pixel of the element.

---

This was a very interesting question. I hope it helped!

Comment: thank u for the answer but ur jsfiddle is not working. pls make the header not to move from it's place while moving scrollbar.

Comment: ur previous answers were working. but problem with this is, the content is scrolled over the bg image but header color is not changing.

Comment: @madhukumar What browser are you using? What example are you using? Are you trying it in jsFiddle?

Comment: @madhukumar Does it throw any errors when you open F12? jsFiddle does NOT need this 'head tag' as it is selected as an extension in jsFiddle.

Comment: I was getting this error when executed in dreamweaver and browser is chrome. "Uncaught TypeMismatchError: The type of an object was incompatible with the expected type of the parameter associated to the object. " jsfiddle is not at all changing colors. header is also not fixed at one place.

Comment: I'm focussing on jsFiddle for now as that one works for me. Does jsFiddle gives any errors?

Comment: Failed to load resource : http://127.0.0.1:10029/public/linkverifierhelper.js            http://127.0.0.1:10029/get-dlv-settings/?_callback=__gwt_jsonp__.P0.onSuccess

Comment: now no errors. only one warning "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44432/discussion-between-nkmol-and-madhu-kumar)

Answer (score -2):

well, you may give background color of the home bar as transparent if you have no band between the home and the content.

```
.home{
 background:transparent;
 }
```

Comment: May be you should change the question so that we can easily understand.

Comment: i don't think the question is not that difficult to understand.